# unable to create a new android project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt

I'm not able to create a new android project in eclipse. Whenever I try to create one & reach last screen of the wizard & hit finish button, a empty project (just folder structure) project with the same name gets created in navigator window but the wizard does not go away.

And in Error console it is showing:

```
   Failed to load properties file for project 'xxxxx'
   Failed to finish PrecompilerBuilder#startupOnInitialize() android
```

It still has that finish button & nothing happens on clicking it again.

tried re-installation but not worked.

operating system: windows 7

what to do? any suggestion......

Comment: Sounds like you need verify Android SDK paths. Please re-install SDK. Add Print screen if you can

Comment: Thanks, but installation of SDK is perfect, showing in the preferences.

Comment: This isnt a solution but try reinstalling eclipse or better download it from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html as a whole.

Comment: but problem is solved just now using the following step...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to give the answer of my own question as,

It is solved by installing API level 16 in the sdk version 21 and ADT version also 21.

Thank You.

Comment: If this was your answer then accept it so that others can use this